# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond while using default proxy

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient, digest-authentication

I'm having an `HTTP` Client program to post an `XML` to the server. It works fine if I directly make a `POST` to the server. But if I route it through Proxy, then I'm getting the exception below:

Proxy Used: `HTTP` without Authentication.

For `POST`, used Digest Authentication.

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:95)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.createTunnelToTarget(DefaultRequestDirector.java:902)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:821)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:647)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at com.actiance.alcatraz.client.HttpClient.send(HttpClient.java:364)
    at com.actiance.alcatraz.client.HttpClient.sendInter(HttpClient.java:240)
    at com.actiance.alcatraz.client.AlcatrazSimpleExporter.export(AlcatrazSimpleExporter.java:98)
    at com.actiance.coreserver.export.alcatraz.AlcatrazExport.doExport(AlcatrazExport.java:121)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.export.exporter.IMExporter._processAlcatraz(IMExporter.java:6345)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.export.exporter.IMExporter._processInteraction(IMExporter.java:2749)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.export.exporter.IMExporter._processInteractions(IMExporter.java:1405)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.export.exporter.IMExporter.test(IMExporter.java:834)
    at com.facetime.imauditor.controller.action.config.ExportAction.test(ExportAction.java:257)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:276)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.LookupDispatchAction.execute(LookupDispatchAction.java:162)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:421)
    at com.facetime.imauditor.controller.action.login.CustomRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(CustomRequestProcessor.java:205)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1164)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:415)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.registration.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.registration.AuthenticationServletFilter.doFilterNoNTLM(AuthenticationServletFilter.java:1144)
    at com.facetime.imcoreserver.registration.AuthenticationServletFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationServletFilter.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.facetime.imauditor.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:369)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1532)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error when the request length is greater than 25600. No idea what's the root of the problem though.

Comment: Here is the solution that may solve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111331/org-apache-http-nohttpresponseexception-xx-xx-xx-xx443-failed-to-respond